# Convert pandas column of date and datetime to date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a column that may contain both date and datetime objects and I want to convert all of them to date.

If I do `df['DT_REFERENCE'].dt.date` it will throw an error on dates.

The best solution I could come up with is

```py
df['DT_REFERENCE'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.date
```

but I was wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: of what dtype is `df['DT_REFERENCE']`? note that there is only `datetime` in `pandas`, i.e. it doesn't matter if you have only time or only date in the input - defaults will be added. if you convert a datetime column to "date-only" with `.dt.date`, the result will be of dtype string (object).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DT_REFERENCE']).dt.date
```